# Cannot create a tag using git from a makefile

Tags: windows, git, makefile, gnu-make

I want to be able to create a tag on a repository when I create a release build.  This is using gnumake and git all running under windows 10, running make from the command prompt.

So in my makefile I added a recipe of:

```
tag_commit:
    git tag tag_name
```

But when I call this git complains that it cannot find the user credentials because they need to be configured.  But I already know they are configured in the global space because if I run `git config --global -l` in the command prompt they show up.  As a test I replaced the tag command with:

```
tag_commit:
    git config --global -l
```

And it returns back saying that it cannot find .gitconfig in the path of where make.exe exists.  It doesn't seem to look in the c:\programdata\git folder where it actually resides.  I have tried adding that folder to the path and it still doesn't work.

I am at a loss where to check next.  Stuff in the makefile that is relying on the path are working and running git by itself can pick up on the global config.  I reckon I am missing something but this is the first time I am getting really fancy with my makefiles and command line git operations.

- Git version: 2.21.0.windows.1
- Make version: 4.2.1

Comment: It would help if you mentioned how did you install `git.exe` (the one which works - is it Git for Windows?) and how did you get `make.exe`. If e.g. `make.exe` is from different `mingw64` distribution, chances are this came with it's own `git.exe` that is looking for `config` in different directory (usually `$HOME/.git/config` rather than `%PROGRAMDATA%\Git\config`). Try to call `which git` from both Git Bash shell (manually) and from your makefile target, are they same paths?

Comment: You've got make and git installed in different environments.

Comment: It is git for window and when I call `which git` from the command prompt and the makefile I get the same path for both `/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jthill I think provided the hint that I needed.  When calling `make.exe` it is running everything as shell script and not just in the command prompt like I was assuming.  When running git from `sh`, for whatever reason, it is using the user folder `/path_to_mingw/home/user_name/` and looking for the `.gitconfig` in there.  But because that does not have my global git config file in it, I created a symbolic link to my `.gitconfig` file.

From the window command prompt, I ran:

```
sh
cd /home/user_name
ln -s /path_to_my_config/.gitconfig
```

And it is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

While not solving your immediate (solved) problem, I'd suggest a different strategy. This because your solution relies changing the source code every time you decide for making a release, which is super annoying.

In the makefile, you can have this line:

```
# ...or whatever default/implicit version string you prefer
VERSION ?= 0.0.0.0
```

The make invocation:

```
make VERSION=1.2.3.4
```

If you have build automation triggered on tag creation, exchange "1.2.3.4" with the tag variable:

```
# Jenkins, powershell (yes, jenkins tag name is in BRANCH_NAME)
make VERSION=$env:BRANCH_NAME
```